# How to avoid running actions when repo is created from a template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, github-actions

I am creating a [template repo](https://github.com/mayank1513/turborepo-template) for building libraries (primarily React18/Next.js libraries with RSC support) using `turborepo`. I have also added workflows to run unit tests on push or PR. There is also a workflow to automate publishing the package to NPM and GitHub Public Repo.

The issue is that the workflows run immediately after a new repo is created using this template. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

After exploring some tweaks and streaks, I found a very simple solution to this issue.

```
jobs:
  test:
    # Don't run just after creating repo from template
    if: github.run_number != 1
```